# $\int_{\Omega}u\operatorname{div} \varphi \,\mathrm{d}x = -\int_{\Omega} \phi \cdot \nabla{u} \,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: differential-geometry, divergence-operator, divergence-theorem

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, $u \in C^1(\Omega)$ and $\phi \in C^{1}_{c}(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^n)$, which denotes the set of continuously differentiable functions $\colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ with compact support. Then, apparently

$$
      \int_{\Omega}u\operatorname{div} \varphi \,\mathrm{d}x = -\int_{\Omega} \phi \cdot \nabla{u} \,\mathrm{d}x  
$$

I actually don't see why this holds. There is one property of divergence that says
$$\mathrm{div}(u \varphi)=u\mathrm{div}(\varphi)+\nabla u \cdot \varphi \, .$$

But if this proves the equation above, then this would imply that

$$\int_{\Omega} \mathrm{div}(u \varphi) \,\mathrm{d}x= 0$$

This looks like an application of the Divergence Theorem, but I'm afraid I don't see the exact argument.

Comment: I suspect some information is missing. I think there are multiple possibilities for $u$ and $\phi$ so that the equation holds or doesn't hold. Perhaps worth noting if the div of a vector field is zero, it can be expressed as the curl of some other vector field.

Comment: If $\Omega$ has a $C^1$ boundary, you can use Gauß theorem $\int_{\Omega} \text{div}(u\phi)dx = \int_{\partial \Omega} u \phi \cdot\textbf{v}dA = 0$, since $\phi$ has a compact support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from the product rule $$\nabla\cdot(u\phi) = u\nabla\cdot\phi + \nabla\cdot\phi$$ and integrate this over an open, bounded region $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ with $C^1$ boundary $\partial\Omega$ to obtain $$\int_\Omega\nabla\
\cdot(u\phi)~\mathrm{d}x = \int_\Omega u\nabla\cdot\phi~\mathrm{d}x + \int_\Omega\nabla u\cdot\phi~\mathrm{d}x.$$ We now apply the Divergence Theorem to the left-hand side to obtain $$\int_\Omega\nabla\
\cdot(u\phi)~\mathrm{d}x = \int_{\partial\Omega} u\phi\cdot\hat{n}~\mathrm{d}S.$$
Substituting this into the first equality yields
$$\int_{\partial\Omega} u\phi\cdot\hat{n}~\mathrm{d}S = \int_\Omega u\nabla\cdot\phi~\mathrm{d}x + \int_\Omega\nabla u\cdot\phi~\mathrm{d}x,$$ or, equivalently, $$\int_\Omega u\nabla\cdot\phi~\mathrm{d}x = -\int_\Omega\nabla u\cdot\phi~\mathrm{d}x + \int_{\partial\Omega} u\phi\cdot\hat{n}~\mathrm{d}S.$$
If $\phi$ has compact support on $\Omega$, then $\phi\cdot\hat{n}$ is identically zero on $\partial\Omega$, so this entire surface integral is zero and we are left with $$\int_\Omega u\nabla\cdot\phi~\mathrm{d}x = -\int_\Omega\nabla u\cdot\phi~\mathrm{d}x,$$ as desired.

Comment: Can you briefly explain why $\phi\cdot\hat{n}$ is identically zero on $\partial\Omega$ if $\phi$ has compact support on $\Omega$? I think this is crucial.

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more careful. We do not have any regularity for the boundary of $\Omega$ (all versions of the divergence theorem I know require the boundary to have some regularity). Of course that is not really an issue as we can just pick a smooth surface $\text{supp}(\phi)\subseteq\Gamma \subseteq \Omega$ and note that $$ \int_\Omega u \, \text{div}(\phi) = \int_\Gamma u \, \text{div}(\phi) $$ and run your argument with $\Gamma$ instead of $\Omega$.

Comment: If $\phi$ has compact support on $\Omega$, then $\phi$ itself is identically zero on $\partial\Omega$, so the dot product with the outer normal vector is as well. The reason that $\phi$ is zero on the boundary is because $\Omega$ is open and its support is compact (and hence closed), so there must always be some room between $\partial\Omega$ and the support of $\phi$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven yes this is true. I edited to note I am assuming a $C^1$ boundary.

Comment: You don't need any boundary regularity for this to be true. Since $u\phi$ is compactlly supported, it extends to a global vector field on $\mathbb R^n$ by defining it to be zero outside the support of $\phi$. Then you can choose a ball $B\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ large enough to contain the support, and apply the divergence theorem on $B$.

Comment: You do need boundary regularity for my argument as written, where I invoke the standard divergence theorem to show a more general result then invoke compactness afterwards.